# How to keep query string parameters in URL when accessing a route of an Angular 2 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, web, angularjs-routing

I have an Angular 2 test app running the latest alpha (37). There are just three routes, that look like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: Home, as: 'home' },
  { path: '/errors', component: Errors, as: 'errors' },
  { path: '/about', component: About, as: 'about' }
])
```

I can access the routes, and when I place query string params in the URL I can read them just fine. However, a few instants after I read the parameters, I noticed that the route loads fine and the URL refreshes, removing the query string parameters.

In other words, accessing this route:

**http://localhost:5555/errors?test=abc**

Loads the `/errors` route, but right after the application loads the URL turns into:

**http://localhost:5555/errors**

That would be confusing to a user. I would like to keep the query string parameters in the URL.

I know, it's in alpha, but is this a bug or I forgot to set something up on the router? How can I keep whatever query string parameters in the URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Alpha 41. The query string is now persisted.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem in Angular 2.0.0 beta 12

Comment: @aokaddaoc Can't reproduce in beta 15. This was the original issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4413. Feel free to comment there or open another issue.

Comment: Reproduced on Angular 4.3.1, 4.4.6 and 5.0.4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598762/angular-erasing-all-query-parameters#47598970

Answer (score 1):

Updating for Angular 2:
To preserve query parameters present in the current url, add

```
// import NavigationExtras 
import  { NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

// Set our navigation extras object
// that contains our global query params

let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      preserveQueryParams: true
    };   

// Navigate to the login page with extras
this.router.navigate(['/someLink'], navigationExtras);
```

For more info, check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters):

Comment: This won't work for direct linking from outside of the site though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
this.router.navigate(['target'], {preserveQueryParams: true});